# Access Specific keys from a javascript object

Tags: javascript

i have used this :-

```
var user = result.user;
alert(JSON.stringify(user));
```

the above code has returned this data

```
{
  "uid": "Kbkd6QMsqIhJ4pe3QXyEUjoAohN2",
  "displayName": "Prince Hamza",
  "photoURL": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg",
  "email": "princehamzi.mine@gmail.com",
  "emailVerified": true,
  "phoneNumber": null,
  "isAnonymous": false,
  "providerData": [
    {
      "uid": "110862942226973616842",
      "displayName": "Prince Hamza",
      "photoURL": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg",
      "email": "princehamzi.mine@gmail.com",
      "phoneNumber": null,
      "providerId": "google.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

but i am unable to Read this data specifically
i want it to return uid , photoURL , Name , Email ;: Particularly

Comment: it is already a JS object. you can use `user.uid` to get the uid and same for the other fields

Comment: man that returned data will produce an error it lacks closing tag of object '}'

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like

```js
      const data = {"uid":"Kbkd6QMsqIhJ4pe3QXyEUjoAohN2","displayName":"Prince Hamza","photoURL":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg","email":"princehamzi.mine@gmail.com","emailVerified":true,"phoneNumber":null,"isAnonymous":false,"providerData":[{"uid":"110862942226973616842","displayName":"Prince Hamza","photoURL":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg","email":"princehamzi.mine@gmail.com","phoneNumber":null,"providerId":"google.com"}] }

    const {uid , photoURL , name , email} = data;

    console.log({ uid, photoURL, name, email});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply return an object containing the elements you want. You don't need to do anything that special. So something like:

```
return {
     "uuid": user.uid,
     "photoURL": user.photoURL,
     "displayName": user.displayName
     ....etc
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. But actually, @Shubham Khatri's answer is the best, but given the context of your question, I thought that destructuring may have been overkill and a little overwhelming.

Comment: @LokiSinclair You are not returning an array but an object and JSON != JS Object

Comment: You're correct. It was early, updated to improve clarity.